# React color ChromePicker alpha slider does not work. Is required use Alpha individual API?

Tags: reactjs, color-picker, react-color

Im trying to implement react-color from https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/#examples
I'm using the ChromePicker component, but the Alpha slider is not working, as expected.
The slider bar is working, but the slider bullet is not moving on.

Here is the https://codesandbox.io/s/react-color-nkh7w example. Is there any component missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `react-color` components (like the `ChromePicker` you are using) do not accept properties for alpha/opacity directly. You have two options:

1. Using the `color.rgb` value only, and don't separate the alpha. If you pass the rgb object as the `color` property), it should work as expected.
2. You can take the color.rgb.a value, convert it to hex, and append it to the `color.hex` string.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the slider alpha is working now. I have updated the codesandbox.

Answer (score 3):

`color.hex` doesn't contain the alpha value. you can you `color.rgba` instead, and also you can convert it to hex with `rgb-hex` package to make it displayable:

```
import { ChromePicker } from "react-color";
import rgbHex from "rgb-hex";
const App = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("#fff");
  return <>
    <ChromePicker
      color={color}
      onChange={c =>
        setColor("#" + rgbHex(c.rgb.r, c.rgb.g, c.rgb.b, c.rgb.a))
      }
    />
    <p>You picked {color}</p>
  </>
}
```